# Rails 3 custom validation and shoulda

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec2, shoulda

Am swinging between Shoulda and Rspec these days. I have read and played around a fair bit with RSpec but not that much with Shoulda.  I find Shoulda's one line assertions easier to read and the test looks cleaner. But when I can't figure out how write a particular assertion in Shoulda I switch to RSpec. Not very happy about it though.

So here is what I did today. I wrote some custom validations for my model `Course`. A course has a `start_date` and an `end_date.` There are a few rules around it.

- `start_date` and `end_date` are both mandatory
- `start_date` cannot be later than today
- `end_date` cannot be before the `start_date`

I know there are quiet a few gems out there that could have done it for me. But coz I am new I thought it might be good idea to do it myself and learn as I go.

So this is what my model looks like

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :batches, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :batches, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:code].blank?}, :allow_destroy => true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, :uniq => true

  validates_presence_of :name, :course_code, :total_seats
  validates_uniqueness_of :category_id, :scope => [:name, :course_code]

  validates :start_date, :presence => true, :course_start_date=>true
  validates :end_date, :presence => true, :course_end_date=>true
end
```

My custom validations are as follows

```
class CourseEndDateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator  
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if object.errors[attribute].blank? && object.errors[:start_date].blank?
      if value < object.start_date
        object.errors[attribute] << "cannot be later than start date"
      end
    end
  end
end

class CourseStartDateValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator  
  def validate_each(object, attribute, value)
    if object.errors[attribute].blank?
      if value < DateTime.now.to_date
        object.errors[attribute] << "cannot be later than today"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And following is my course_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'require 'date'

describe Course do

  context  'validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:course_code)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:start_date)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:end_date)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:total_seats)}

    date = DateTime.now.to_date
    it { should allow_value(date).for(:start_date) }
    it { should_not allow_value(date - 10 ).for(:start_date) }
    it {should allow_value(date + 10).for(:end_date)}
  end

  context  'associations' do
    it { should belong_to(:category)}
    it { should have_many(:batches).dependent(:destroy)}
    it { should have_and_belong_to_many(:students) }
  end

  it " end date should not be before course start date" do
    course = FactoryGirl.build(:course, :end_date=>'2011-12-10')
    course.should be_invalid
  end
end
```

Now before I wrote the last "it" block using Rspec I had something like this in my validations context

```
context  'validations' do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:name)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:course_code)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:start_date)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:end_date)}
    it { should validate_presence_of(:total_seats)}

    date = DateTime.now.to_date
    it { should allow_value(date).for(:start_date) }
    it { should_not allow_value(date - 10 ).for(:start_date) }
    it { should allow_value(date + 10).for(:end_date)}
    it { should_not allow_value(date - 10).for(:end_date)} # <-------------------
  end
```

And I got the following failure

```
Failures:

  1) Course validations
     Failure/Error: it { should_not allow_value(date - 10).for(:end_date)}
       Expected errors when end_date is set to Fri, 9 Dec 2011, got errors: ["name can't be blank (nil)", "course_code can't be blank (nil)", "total_seats can't be blank (nil)", "start_date can't be blank (nil)"]
```

Am not sure what am I doing wrong here. Is it my custom validation code that is not correct or I need to setup something before I run the last assertion so that start_date is not nil when testing end_date?

The validations work fine in the view. I mean I get the right validation errors depending on the kind of data I input. But am test is failing. I have been looking at this for a while now but cannot figure out what exactly am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could tackle this in one of two two ways:

Either you need to place you `date = DateTime.now.to_date` into to `before(:each)` block.

```
context  'validations' do
  before(:each) { date = DateTime.now.to_date }

  it { should allow_value(date).for(:start_date) }
  it { should_not allow_value(date - 10 ).for(:start_date) }
  it { should allow_value(date + 10).for(:end_date)}
  it { should_not allow_value(date - 10).for(:end_date)}
end
```

Or you could use the rails date helpers.

```
context  'validations' do
  it { should allow_value(Date.today).for(:start_date) }
  it { should_not allow_value(10.days.ago).for(:start_date) }
  it { should allow_value(10.days.from_now).for(:end_date)}
  it { should_not allow_value(10.days.ago).for(:end_date)}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@nickgrim already answered the question, but I want to add a comment. The point of `describe` and `it` is to encourage sentences that start with the words "describe" and "it". In your example, you've got this:

```
it " end date should not be before course start date" do
  # ...
```

"it end date ...." is not a sentence. Please write that as something like:

```
it "validates that end date should be >= start date" do
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I thought when the steps are printed out on console they should make readable sentences. so my output on console when I run my spec is something like this `Course
   end date should not be before course start date
  validations
    should require name to be set
    should require course_code to be set ...
` What you are suggesting is correct for someone reading the spec. Am not sure which approach to follow now. Any thoughts?

Comment: From my perspective, we should work to make the spec and the console output readable. But if you can't have both (kind see why) the output of the console is way more important, if you use the output in verbose mode. If you only use the dots, then the spec is more important. But I definitely like to see a good readable console output, specially when the tests fail :)